# scrlttr2 reuse text of subject in letter again

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

Im tring to reuse the text of subject in the letter so right after \opening{}.

It is predefined like this:

> \setkomavar{subject}{MySubjectText}

So im using this line several times in the text again and like to automate the print...

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\usekomavar{subject}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\usekomavar{subject}` you can reuse your subject text:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{subject}{MySubjectText}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xx}
\opening{Hello}

The subject text can be reused: \usekomavar{subject}

\closing{Regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And i found out how to use different parts within the Komavar:

```
%subject
\newcommand{\presubject}{Appling as }
\newcommand{\subjectmain}{Software Test Engineer }
\newcommand{\subjectend}{(80\%)}

\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\subjectname}{\presubject}
\setkomavar{subject}{\subjectmain\subjectend}
```

And use just the part of the jobtitle in the letter body like this:

```
\subjectmain
```